# Android background looks stretched

Tags: android, layout, splash-screen

I was trying to make a splash screen on Android using the HVGA resolution (320x480 - portrait). I made a splash screen in PNG with the HVA resolution but the background comes out stretched horizontally.

My splash.xml code as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/background_320x480">
</LinearLayout>
```

I have no code in the java file.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it in full-screen mode, or do you have the title bar and/or status bar?

Comment: Hi Rajath, nope there is neither title bar nor status bar. Yes it is in full-screen mode as it is just a splash screen that stays on for 3 seconds only.

Comment: Try setting the background as mentioned [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889507/why-is-my-imported-png-such-low-quality

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and better to show image into imageview control..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/splash"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```