# Why is my imported PNG such low quality

Tags: android, background

I am doing:

```
android:background="@drawable/mobile_vforum_bg"
```

in the main.xml file to just set the BG.

It works, just the quality of the image is very poor when viewed on the emulator. Its a PNG at 320x480 (96dpi and the same in the low, med and high folder). When I was using Titanium to build my android app, it looked fine. I am now using eclipse and java and it looks bad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this issue while setting a high resolution image as an activity's background and I was able to solve it by using the following java code from the Activity's `onCreate()` method.

```
        BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        myOptions.inDither = true;
        myOptions.inScaled = false;
        myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        myOptions.inDither = false;
        myOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap preparedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(yourAppName.getSharedApplication().getResources(),
                R.drawable.yourImage, myOptions);
        Drawable background = new BitmapDrawable(preparedBitmap);
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutId))
            .setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Also don't set the background from the layout xml if you are using this code. In case this doesn't work try setting the following lines outside the application tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Hope this Helps!!!

Answer (score 9):

Try to move it to the "res/drawable_hdpi" folder, that worked for me.

Comment: I have the same image in all three folders already. Maybe the emulator I am testing on is set to low dpi or something

Comment: The SDK optimizes all images, so I think there is another option - put it into /res/raw folder (files you put there remain unchanged during build process) and load it manually using [Resources.openRawResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)).

Comment: I cant make that call in the XML though like how I am doing it above. How would I set the background of the app using java then?

Comment: `yourview.setBackgroundDrawable(img);`

Comment: I ended up making a new virtual device with some slightly different settings and the background looks fine now. I am still using the XML method.